# Change tracking, transaction log out of space and recovery mode change

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I observed quite strange behavior of change tracking that I'm not able to explain. Few unusual things happened:

- DB was running fine, we read change tracking information as usually, up to version `A`. DB was running in full recovery mode.
- The transaction log ran out of space, all writes were failing with `The transaction log for database '...' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'`.
- Customer shrunk the DB log file and set the DB to simple recovery mode.
- We queried the change tracking again, from version `A`. But some records that were obviously inserted after version `A` were returned only as updates and not as inserts.

The change tracking retention period is way longer than the time between first and last point. The PK is not identity/sequence field, value is inserted by third party service.

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5, build 17763

It looks to me like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something...

I know that the documentation says: "If you delete a row and then insert a row that has the old primary key, the change is seen as an update to all columns in the row". But that does not seem to be the case here and also it would explain it for few rows, but it happened for hundreds of rows.

Does anyone know whether the change of the recovery mode or shrink of the log file could somehow cause described behavior?

Comment: To be clear, the feature being used is Change Tracking or Change Data Capture?

Comment: @J.D. It's change tracking

Comment: "*Customer shrunk the DB log file and set the DB to simple recovery mode.*" - These are very likely the culprits to your issues, but I don't know enough about Change Tracking to definitively say, without more research. I do know the Transaction Log is used for a lot of similar features though. Regardless, those are silly things to do when you run out of Transaction Log space. Why didn't they just perform a Transaction Log Backup?